# JPA2.1 - Calling a stored procedure which returns CLOB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA 2.1 with hibernate as implemention vendor.

I am trying to call a stored procedure which returns a CLOB.

```
   StoredProcedureQuery storedProcQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("pkg_test.get_clob");
        storedProcQuery .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcQuery .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcQuery .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, oracle.sql.CLOB.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        storedProcQuery .setParameter(1, "ABCD");
        storedProcQuery .setParameter(2, "XYZ");
        storedProcQuery.execute();   //here i get the following exception. 

*Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_CLOB'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)*
```

Here i am passing the type as oracle.sql.CLOB.class which is an implementation of java.sql.CLOB.

I have tested the the same PL/SQL procedure with the pure JDBC implementation and its working fine.

But want to use JPA2.1 features.

Can you please suggest what i am doing wrong above ?

thank you.

Comment: I'd add the SP signature to the question. I bet you'll need some custom hibernate configuration to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hibernate or jpa or java issue.
This error comes from your oracle jdbc driver in call to 'GET_CLOB' procedure

Check oracle db error codes manual :

**ORA-06550**:  line string, column string:string

Cause:  A PL/SQL compilation error has occurred. The numbers given for line and column are the location in the PL/SQL block where the error occurred.

Action: Refer to the following PL/SQL messages for more information about the error.

The ORA-06550 is error points to the location in the PL/SQL where the syntax error occurred and it is followed by a more descriptive message of the compile-time error:

Comment: if i test the same stored procedure with a pure JDBC approach then its works fine. So i guess the procedure is fine as i have tested with the JDBC approach. I guess the issue with the paramter types that i am passing in the JPA stored procedure paramter registration. what do you say ?

Comment: @Subba Exception appears to be low level (check last lines log). If it's not procedure fault, it's oracle jdbc driver customization.